# c# Básico!.Como invocar a una función que recibe un parametro?

Tags: c#

Les cuento que estoy comenzando con C# y me encuentro perdida!.

Tengo unas opciones como calculadora donde se pueden hacer distintas operaciones.

Se me ocurrió validar las opciones que ingresó a mano (si, lo sé ...es para practicar y fue un ejercicio que se me ocurrió)  entonces lo que hago es creo una función donde lo primero que hace es evaluar si lo que ingresó el usuario es un valor numerico. Para esto creé una función que la idea es que evalue y muestre en pantalla un mensaje si no ingresa un número o no , luego desde el programa invoco esta función con el fin de que me imprima en pantalla el resultado..

el tema es q no funca y no se ..es bien basico

```
namespace Calculadora
{
    class Program
    {
        string Mensaje;

        static string validoOpcion(out int Opcion)
        {

            Boolean Numerico;
            Numerico = false;
            Numerico = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Opcion);
            if (!Numerico)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("No es un numero lo que ingresaste!");
                Mensaje = ("No es un numero lo que ingresaste!");
            } else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Opcion Valida");
                Mensaje = ("Opcion Valida");
            }

            return Mensaje();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            double NumeroUno = 0f;
            double NumeroDos = 0f;
            double Resultado = 0;
            int Opcion = 0;
            string Operacion;

            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la calculadora!. Favor de ingresar su nombre");
            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hola " + nombre + ". Aquí podrás realizar las siguientes operaciones");
            Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(" Opción 1: Multipicar");
            Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(" Opción 2: Sumar");
            Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(" Opción 3: Dividir");
            Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
            Console.WriteLine(" Opción 4: Restar");
            Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
            Opcion = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(validoOpcion());
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

En el return del método 'validoOpcion' estás regresando la variable mensaje como si fuese otro método:

```
 return Mensaje();
```

cuando debería ser:

```
 return Mensaje;
```

Aparte, cuando llamas al método 'validoOpcion', te falta pasarle el parámetro que definiste:

```
 Opcion = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine(validoOpcion());
```

Debería ser:

```
 Opcion = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 Console.WriteLine(validoOpcion(out Opcion ));
```

Aun así no funcionará, te explico, en el cuerpo del programa, solicitas la opción:

```
 Opcion = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Eso está bien, bueno, mas o menos, porque si escribes una letra te va a dar un error, pero bueno, la cosa es que una vez que llamas al método 'validoOpcion', vuelves a solicitar la opción, es decir, de nada sirve que lo pidas antes de llamar al método si dentro del método la vuelves a pedir.

Yo lo haría así, en el cuerpo del programa:

```
Opcion = Console.ReadLine();
```

Luego llamaría al método así:

```
Console.WriteLine(validoOpcion(Opcion));
```

Y el método lo modificaría así:

```
    static string validoOpcion(string Opcion)
    {
        boolean Numerico = false;
        int numero;
        Numerico = Int32.TryParse(Opcion, out numero);

        if (!Numerico)
        {
            Mensaje = "No es un numero lo que ingresaste!";
        } 
        else
        {
            Mensaje = "Opcion Valida";
        }

        return Mensaje;
    }
```

O refactorizado para que quede mas pequeño:

```
static string validoOpcion(string Opcion)
{
    int numero;
    var Numerico = Int32.TryParse(Opcion, out numero);

    return Numerico ?? "Opcion Valida" : "No es un numero lo que ingresaste!";  
}
```

O, si vas a utilizar el número dentro de validoOpcion para aprovechar de hacer alguna operación:

```
static string validoOpcion(string Opcion)
{
    int numero;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Opcion, out numero))
    {
        // haces lo que quieras hacer con el número, quedó guardado en la variable numero...
        Mensaje = "Opcion Valida";
    }
    else
    {
        Mensaje = "No es un numero lo que ingresaste!";
    }    

    return Mensaje;  
}
```

Como ves, hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!  La verdad que me quedó super claro con la explicación.. Sé que tal vez sea básico esto pero estoy arrancando y not engo a nadie para consultarle cerca ! y el foro es la mejor opción por gente como ustedes! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas definiendo un parametro en `validoOpcion()` entiendo que es este el que quiere validar, pero alli veo que solicitas la entrada de datos dos veces, una en el `Main` y otra dentro de esta funciona, deberia ser una sola.

Podria ser algo como esto

```
static string validoOpcion(string Opcion)
{
    string Mensaje = "";
    int numero = 0;

    if (Int32.TryParse(Opcion, out numero))
    {
        Mensaje = "Opcion Valida"; 
    } 
    else
    {
        Mensaje = "No es un numero lo que ingresaste!";
    }

    return Mensaje;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //resto codigo

    string Opcion = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(validoOpcion(Opcion));
    Console.ReadKey();  

}
```

La idea es que desde `Main` tomes la valor de la opcion y que `validoOpcion` se encargue unicamente de valir, retornando el mensaje

Comment: Muchas gracias!entendí!Gracias por la respuesta!